# Problema Array push javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy intentando obtener los datos de unos amigos de una base de datos `Mongo` y es como que el `push( )` del *array* no hace bien su trabajo.

```
let friendsData = [ ];

friends.forEach( x => {
  criterio = { "email": x.friend };
  gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
    if( usuarios == null ) {
      res.send( "Error al listar " );
    } else {
      friendsData.push( usuarios );
    }

    console.log( friendsData );
  } );

  console.log( friendsData );
} );
```

Y al ultimo `console.log( )` el *array* está vacío, pero en el primer `console.log( )` si salen los datos que deben salir.

He probado tambien por si es la asincronia del forEach haciendolo con un bucle simple y el error sigue ocurriendo, no se si sera por que `Mongo` haga sus llamadas tambien de manera asincrona.

Comment: Problema de asincronía. El método `forEach()` no trabaja de forma asíncrona. Tu array se llenará en un momento posterior a tu último llamado a `console.log()`. El primer `console.log()` de hecho se ejecuta después del segundo. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras he intenado modificarlo a un bucle simple y sigue siendo ocurriendo lo mismo, sabrias alguna manera de arreglarlo. Muchas Gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es de asincronía. Y es que todas las operaciones sobre base de datos (sin importar el motor que uses) son asíncronas.

Todos los [métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array#M.C3.A9todos) de los tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) de Javascript (por lo tanto de NodeJS), son métodos sincrónicos.

Un ejemplo:

```js
let friends = [
  {
    name: 'Mauricio',
    country: 'Spain',
    favoriteProgrammingLanguage: 'Javascript'
  },
  {
    name: 'Aitor',
    country: 'Spain',
    favoriteProgrammingLanguage: 'Javascript'
  }
];

const miMetodoAsincrono = friend => {
  return setTimeout(() => { return console.log(friend.name)}, 0);
}

friends.forEach(miMetodoAsincrono);
console.log('¿Estoy de último?');
```

**¿Cómo podemos corregir este comportamiento?**

No se puede, se debe aprender a trabajar con el comportamiento asíncrono de las consultas a Bases de Datos.

Una forma de obtener los resultados es devolver una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y usar [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all).

Sin embargo debes tomar en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Toda lógica para trabajar con el resultado de una Promesa debes escribirla en el método `then()` de la misma. Los posibles errores los manejas en el método `catch()`.
2. Puedes usar `await` sólo dentro de un ámbito (función) tipo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona).
3. Si vas a usar `await`, debes envolver la llamada a tu método asíncrono dentro de un bloque [`try catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como no sé a ciencia cierta si usas directamente el Driver de MongoDB para NodeJS o tal vez usas Mongoose como ODM, sólo puedo asegurar que el método `gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios()` es asíncrono al ver que pasas una función `callback` al mismo. Entonces crearé un envoltorio a dicho método para que devuelva una Promesa:

```js
// dentro de la función que se ejecuta para cada elemento de la lista
criterio = { "email": x.friend };
// esto devuelve una Promesa
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // esta Promesa es un envoltorio para el método obtenerUsuarios
  gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
    if( usuarios == null ) {
      return reject("Error al listar");
    }
    resolve(usuarios);
  }); // fin método callback
});// fin Promesa
```

Con esto ya tengo un envoltorio que devuelve una Promesa, ahora veamos cómo usar `Promise.all()` usando el resultado de este envoltorio para cada elemento de la lista.

El método `Promise.all()` recibe como argumento una lista (iterable) de Promesas. Por lo tanto debo usar un método de los tipo `Array` que aplicado sobre cada elemento me devuelva una lista. El método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) no me sirve para este propósito ya que no me devuelve una lista sino que me devuelve `undefined`.

Usaremos el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) que me devuelve un nuevo `Array` con el resultado de la función pasada como argumento aplicada a cada elemento de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```js
friends.map(x => {
  // dentro de la función que se ejecuta para cada elemento de la lista
  criterio = { "email": x.friend };
  // esto devuelve una Promesa
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // esta Promesa es un envoltorio para el método obtenerUsuarios
    gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
      if( usuarios == null ) {
        return reject("Error al listar");
      }
      resolve(usuarios);
    }); // fin método callback
  });// fin Promesa
}) // fin método map
```

Como el método `map()` me devuelve un iterable cuyos elementos son todos Promesas, puedo pasar directamente dicho iterable como argumento a la función `Promise.all()`. Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
Promise.all(
  friends.map(x => {
    criterio = { "email": x.friend };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
        if( usuarios == null ) {
          return reject("Error al listar");
        }
        resolve(usuarios);
      }); // fin método callback
    });// fin Promesa
  }) // fin método map
);// fin Promise.all()
```

Ahora `Promise.all()` es una lista de elementos de tipo promesa, cuyos valores serán accesibles en algún momento futuro. Y para acceder a dichos valores, usamos `then()`. Si alguna de la Promesas es rechazada, toda la lista será rechazada y `Promise.all()` devolverá un objeto de error que podemos capturar con el mñetodo `catch()`.

Entonces para trabajar con la lista de Promesas debes hacerlo así:

```js
Promise.all(
  friends.map(x => {
    criterio = { "email": x.friend };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
        if( usuarios == null ) {
          return reject("Error al listar");
        }
        resolve(usuarios);
      }); // fin método callback
    });// fin Promesa
  }) // fin método map
)
.then(lista => {
  // sólo aquí tienes acceso al resultado de la Promesa
  console.log(lista);
})
.catch(error => {
  // aqui manejamos cualquier posible error
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

Te puedes ver tentado a escribir lo siguiente:

```js
let lista = Promise.all(...).then(list => { return list}).catch(...);
console.log(lista);
```

Lo cierto es que eso no funcionará, ya que `lista` es en realidad una Promesa y no una lista. Puedes comprobarlo haciendo:

```js
let lista = Promise.all(...);
lista.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Ahora, volviendo al ejemplo que puse al inicio, veamos como funcionaría todo esto:

```js
let friends = [
  {
    name: 'Mauricio',
    country: 'Spain',
    favoriteProgrammingLanguage: 'Javascript'
  },
  {
    name: 'Aitor',
    country: 'Spain',
    favoriteProgrammingLanguage: 'Javascript'
  }
];

const miMetodoAsincrono = friend => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!friend.name) {
      return reject('Amigo sin nombre');
    }
    resolve(friend.name);
  });
}

let miLista = Promise.all(
  friends.map(friend => {
    return miMetodoAsincrono(friend);
  })
);

// miLista es una Promesa (puedo usar then y catch)
miLista
.then(lista => {
  console.log('Friends:', lista.join(', '));
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});

console.log('¿Estoy de último?');
```

**Usando `async/await`**

Básicamente se realiza el mismo procedimiento, con la excepción que para usar `await` debemos encontrarnos en un entorno tipo `async`.

Supongamos que toda tu lógica va dentro de un método llamado `listar()`, pues debemos declarar ese método como tipo `async`:

```js
const listar = async () => {
  // para usar await con Promesas, debo usar un bloque try catch:
  try {
    let lista = Promise.all(
      friends.map(x => {
        criterio = { "email": x.friend };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          gestorBD.obtenerUsuarios( criterio, function( usuarios ) {
            if( usuarios == null ) {
              return reject("Error al listar");
            }
            resolve(usuarios);
          }); // fin método callback
        });// fin Promesa
      }) // fin método map
    ); // fin Promise.all
    // ahora lista si que contiene el resultado
    console.log(lista);
  } catch(error) {
    // aqui capturo cualquier posible error
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Seguro te verás tentado a hacer:

```
return lista;
```

dentro de tu método `async`, pero lo cierto es que toda función `async` devuelve una Promesa, por lo tanto tu lista sólo estará disponible fuera de tu función `async` cuando invoques al método `then` de dicha Promesa:

```js
const listar = async () => {
  ...
}

listar().then(lista => { ... }).catch(...);
```

Y estamos como al principio.

La lección aquí es aprender a utilizar los métodos asíncronos. Con el objeto `Promise` de Javascript se hace bastante fácil, y usando `async / await` el código es más legible.