# manejo de errores con exec

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo un codigo que funciona bien de la siguiente manera:

```
function actualizarProceso(lista) {

        const arregloDePromesas = []


        lista.forEach((elemento) => {


            var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento.user },
                { $set: { "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela, "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin, "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos, "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token } }
            ).exec()

            arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)

            var asigSos = UserSos.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento._id },
                { $set: { "flagSos": true } }
            ).exec()
            arregloDePromesas.push(asigSos)



        })

        return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas);
    }
```

pero debo manejar los errores por lo tanto realice el cambio respectivos, si se ejecuta el primer exec debe si y solo si ejecutar el segundo exec, los cambios fueron entamente en el exec el codigo quedo de esta manera:

```
  function actualizarProceso(lista) {

        const arregloDePromesas = []


        lista.forEach((elemento) => {


            var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento.user },
                { $set: { "pasarela": elemento.previo.pasarela, "fecha_fin": elemento.previo.fecha_fin, "dispositivos": elemento.previo.dispositivos, "estado_token": elemento.previo.estado_token } }
            ).exec((err, response)=>{

                if (err){
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)

                var asigSos = UserSos.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": elemento._id },
                    { $set: { "flagSos": true } }
                ).exec((err, response)=>{
                    if (err){
                        return console.log(err)
                    }
                    arregloDePromesas.push(asigSos)

                })

            })

        })

        return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas);
    }
```

pero no me funciona, estoy comenzando con node y javascript, disculpen si los errores son muy evidentes, no puedo trabajar con asyn/await porque la version de Node es 7.02 y la de Moongose es 4.7, de antemano gracias

Comment: El método `forEach()` no hace lo que aspiras que haga. Creo que haré una pregunta canónica sobre este tema. Ya he [respondido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353944/problema-array-push-javascript/353960#353960) antes exactamente este tipo de problemas, te marcaré la pregunta como duplicada. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema Array push javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353944/problema-array-push-javascript)

Comment: Hola y gracias estuve leyendo y es bastante completa, el problema (y disculpa si no entiendo) es que cuando el actualiza una coleccion ESE mismo elemento necesito que actualice en otra coleccion, es lo que no entiendo como hacer...

Comment: si y gracias por ayuda Mauricio, otra cosa es que por versiones del node no puedo utilizar async /await..gracias nuevamente @MauricioContreras

Comment: ¿Y qué versión usas? La verdad que hacer esto con `async / await` es mejor de cara a la legibilidad del código. ¿Podrías agregar a tu pregunta la versión de Node, Mongoose y MongoDB? Saludos

Comment: Node 7.02 y moongose 4.7, Gracias Mauricio

Comment: Tiene soporte completa hasta la version `7.6.0`. Antes de eso (`7.0.0`) tienes que poner la bandera `--harmony`. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona

Comment: Lo probamos con async/await y no funciono, todo los bloques de codigos estan construidos solo a base de promesas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Uno de los problemas que veo en tu implementación es que estás tratando las consultas (`queries`) de Mongoose como si se tratasen de Promesas, [pero no lo son](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises).

Todas las consultas de Mongoose devuelven un Objeto tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#query-js). Si leemos la documentación de Mongoose 4.x acerca de las [consultas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/queries.html) se lee: (traducción propia)

> Cuando una función *callback*:
>
> - es pasada, la operación se ejecutará de inmediato con los resultados pasados al *callback*.
> - no es pasada, una instancia de *Query* es devuelta, la cual provee una interfaz especial de constructor de consultas.

Otro de los errores es que no estás actuando en caso de que una Promesa sea rechazada, de hecho si hay algún error en el proceso de actualización de alguno de los datos, sólo haces un `console.log()` del mismo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dicho esto, vamos a corregir los errores de la implementación tal como la tienes actualmente.

Veo que en tu código creas una variable llamada `arregloDePromesas`, la cual pretendes llenar usando el resultado de tus consultas a MongoDB por cada elemento de la lista recibida.

En los comentarios planteas que [no puedes usar `async / await`](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) debido a la versión de Node (7.0.2) con la que trabajas. Pero [si puedes usar Promesas](https://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Promise).

Vamos a enfocarnos en el método de Mongoose que utilizas para realizar la actualización del documento: `findOneAndUpdate()`.

Como ya sabemos, el mismo no devuelve una Promesa, sino un Objeto de tipo `Query`, de Mongoose.

Para tener realmente una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), debemos envolver el resultado de dicho proceso dentro de una Promesa.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });
```

Una forma de hacer esta envoltura en tu código sería la siguiente:

```js
const promesa = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": elemento.user }, 
    {new: true}, 
    (error, updatedDoc) => { ... }
  );
});
```

Como puedes ver estoy usando una función `callback` que recibe 2 parámetros: `error` y `updatedDoc`.

Pero para que `updatedDoc` sea realmente el documento actualizado y no el documento encontrado antes de la actualización, paso un segundo parámetro al método `findOneAndUpdate()`. Este segundo parámetro es un objeto con un atributo llamado `new` cuyo valor es un booleano, que por defecto (si no lo indicamos) es `false`, por esta razón lo establezco como `true`.

Puedes leer más al respecto en la documentación del método [`findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Como tu deseas procesar una lista de Promesas con [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all), debemos encontrar una forma de que por cada elemento de nuestra lista podamos devolver la Promesa que envuelve al método `findOneAndUpdate()`.

Tu usas el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) que recorre todos los elementos de un Array. Pero no devuelve nada (realmente devuelve `undefined`). Por lo tanto es mejor usar el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) que sí nos devuelve un Array, cuyos elementos serán el resultado de la operación realizada sobre cada elemento del Array original.

Entonces vamos a reescribir la lógica de tu función así:

```js
function actualizarProceso(lista) {
  const promesas = lista.map(elemento => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });
  });

  return Promise.all(promesas);
}
```

Con esto ya tienes la parte externa resuelta. Ahora debemos trabajar en la lógica para realizar las 2 actualizaciones. Ambas dependen de un valor de cada elemento de la lista.

La primera actualización la haces sobre el modelo `User` usando como filtro el campo `elemento.user`, la segunda actualización la haces sobre el modelo `UserSos`, usando como filtro el campo `elemento._id`.

Las actualizaciones las haces en cadena, es decir, primero realizas una actualización y al obtener el resultado de la misma realizas la segunda actualización.

Pues la lógica usando funciones `callback` sería la siguiente:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: elemento.user },
  { new: true},
  (error, updatedUser) => {
    // aquí debemos manejar el error (si lo hay) de la primera actualización
    // como estamos dentro de una Promesa, usaremos reject
    if(error) return reject(error);

    // podemos llamar ahora al segundo método de actualización
    UserSos.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: elemento._id },
      {new: true},
      (error, updatedAsigSos) => {
        // nuevamente para manejar el error dentro de una Promesa devolvemos
        // la función de rechazo:
        if(error) return reject(error);
        // ahora ya podemos resolver la promesa, y construiremos un objeto
        // con los 2 resultados obtenidos
        resolve({user: updatedUser, asigSos: updatedAsigSos});
      }
    );// fin update asigsos
  }
);//fin update user
```

Esa sería una forma de trabajar con ambas actualizaciones usando `callbacks`.

Este código también se puede reescribir usando el método `exec()` el cual nos devuelve un Objeto `thenable`. De hecho devuelve un Objeto conocido como *fully-fledged* Promise. Esta es la definición de [*Promises/A+*](https://promisesaplus.com/).

La diferencia con una Promesa tal como la estamos construyendo es que en *Promise/A+* no se implementa un método `catch()` ni el método `finally()`. Por lo cual no es adecuado usar estos objetos como elementos de nuestro arreglo de Promesas, ya que `Promise.all()` espera una lista de *Promesas* y no una lista de *Promesas/A+*.

Para trabajar con este tipo de Promesas/A+, igualmente debemos envolver nuestro método de actualización en una Promesa.

Una forma sería:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const promesa1 = User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: elemento.user}, {new:true}).exec();
  promesa1.then(updatedUser => {
    // la primera promesa fue resuelta, puedo llamar al segundo método
    const promesa2 = UserSos.findOneAndUpdate({_id: elemento._id}, {new:true}).exec();
    promesa2.then(updatedAsigSos => {
      //la segunda promesa fue resuelta, puedo resolver mi Promesa inicial
      return resolve({user: updatedUser, asigSos: updatedAsigSos});
    },
    error => {
      // manejo de la promesa2 rechazada
      return reject(error);
    }
  },
  error => {
    //manejo de la promesa1 rechazada
    return reject(error);
  });
});
```

Independientemente del tipo de método que uses, siempre usarás un envoltorio de Promesa, para manejar correctamente el método asíncrono de actualización de documentos en MongoDB usando Mongoose.

Por último falta implementar `Promise.all()`. Tomando el código en donde se usan funciones `callback` tenemos que tu función puede verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
function actualizarProceso(lista) {
  return Promise.all(lista.map(elemento => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: elemento.user },
        { new: true},
        (error, updatedUser) => {
          // aquí debemos manejar el error (si lo hay) de la primera actualización
          // como estamos dentro de una Promesa, usaremos reject
          if(error) return reject(error);

          // podemos llamar ahora al segundo método de actualización
          UserSos.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: elemento._id },
            {new: true},
            (error, updatedAsigSos) => {
              // nuevamente para manejar el error dentro de una Promesa devolvemos
              // la función de rechazo:
              if(error) return reject(error);
              // ahora ya podemos resolver la promesa, y construiremos un objeto
              // con los 2 resultados obtenidos
              resolve({user: updatedUser, asigSos: updatedAsigSos});
            }
          );// fin update asigsos
        }
      ); // fin update user
    }); // fin new Promise
  }) // fin lista.map
  ); // fin Promise.all
} // fun función
```

Y para usar correctamente tu método en otra parte del programa puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
actualizarProceso(miLista)
.then(listaResultados =>  {
  listaResultados.forEach(elemento => {
    console.log(elemento);
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

¿Porqué uso `then()` y `catch()`? Porque en mi función estoy retornando `Promise.all()` que devuelve una Promesa.

Espero que esta respuesta aclare un poco los conceptos y no olvides siempre consultar la documentación, ya que en definitiva todo está allí.

Comment: Sólo un apunte, las *queries* de *mongoose* no devuelven `Promise`, efectivamente. En el ejemplo del OP, usa el método `exec()`, que es la forma que ofrece *mongoose* para convertir las *queries* a `Promise`. Puedes ahorrarte un poco de implementación en tu respuesta para usar las *build-in promises* de *mongoose*.

Comment: @VRoxa Devuelve la implementación inicial de [Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), es decir un objeto *thenable*, que no es lo mismo que la implementación ES2015 de las Promesas, sobre la cual se basa el método `Promise.all()`. Es por ello que realizo el envoltorio aún cuando se usa `exec()` para convertir ese objeto *thenable* en una Promesa y capturar el posible error. Saludos

Comment: La función `Promise.all` funciona con cualquier objeto que implemente una función `then` como propiedad. Los llamados *thenables*, sí. [Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/ukhwg263/2/) tienes un pequeño ejemplo que acabo de hacer. Del mismo modo funciona prácticamente toda la API de `Promise`, con *thenables*

Comment: @VRoxa, tienes razón. Si deseas aclarar el punto en mi respuesta puedes hacerlo. Entiendo que el OP desea realizar 2 *update* y poder capturar el *error*. Si bien una `Query` de Mongoose (4.x) implementa `then` y `catch`, en mi experiencia no es óptimo usarla como una Promesa, por el hecho de que volver a hacer `then` sobre una `Query` repite la misma, ya que al fin y al cabo no es una Promesa. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para manejar los errores bastaria usar `catch` omitiendo por cada promesa el callback.

De esta manera:

```
  function actualizarProceso(lista) {
    const arregloDePromesas = [];

    lista.forEach(elemento => {
      var promesa = User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: elemento.user },
        {
          $set: {
            pasarela: elemento.previo.pasarela,
            fecha_fin: elemento.previo.fecha_fin,
            dispositivos: elemento.previo.dispositivos,
            estado_token: elemento.previo.estado_token
          }
        }
      ).exec();

      arregloDePromesas.push(promesa);

      var asigSos = UserSos.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: elemento._id },
        { $set: { flagSos: true } }
      ).exec();
      arregloDePromesas.push(asigSos);
    });

    return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas);
  }
```

Esto lo ejecutarias de esta manera:

```
actualizarProceso(tuListaElementos)
.then(resultados=>{
 //resultados es un arreglo. Por la forma de tu codigo te va a traer el codigo
 //de la siguiente manera

 var resultadoUser = tuListaElementos[0]
 var resultadoUserSos = tuListaElementos[1]

 //... Esto lo puedes meter en un for y todos los resultados pares incluyendo el 0
 // son resultados de User, y los impares Usersos.  


})
.catch(err=>{
    // Aqui se van a capturar los errores de todas las promesas 
    // que ejecute Promise.all, aunque el funcionamiento de all
    // es que si una promesa tiene un error, detiene la ejecucion de 
    // todas las demas. 
    console.log('tus errores", err)
    //En el caso de que uses expressjs puedes usar next(err)
    y capturar en un middleware todos los errores. 

})
```